# Post Thumbnail URL isn't pulling into the background of div

Tags: wp-query

I updated my code. I swapped returns with echoes. The only issue is that the post_thumbnail_url isn't pulling into the background of div.

```
<?php
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'category_name' => 'news',
            );
            $news_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $news_query->have_posts() ) :
                ?>

                <?php
                    $featured_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'full' );
                ?>

                <?php echo '<div class="recent-news-banner" style="background: url(' . $featured_img . ') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">'; ?>

                <?php
                while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) : $news_query->the_post();
                ?>
                    <?php
                        $date = Date('F j, Y');
                        $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
                        $link = get_the_permalink($post->ID);               
                    ?>

                    <?php echo '<div class="' . '' . '"><div class="meta-date">' . Date('F j, Y') . '</div><div class="meta-info"><div class="meta-title"><h5><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h5></div></div>'; ?>

                <?php
                endwhile;
                ?>
                <?php echo '</div>'; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e( "No News Found", 'news' ); ?></p>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif 
        ?>
```

Comment: try removing all lines that start with $html_out and make sure the WP-Query is working first.

Comment: Have you stepped through the [basic WordPress debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) process?

Comment: Unrelated but you should move the wp_reset_postdata inside the if statement, you should only call it if you called the_post else you might be reseting something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing return to echo.

You are not in a function and you are using return in the global scope which just stops the current script.

Comment: I think the featured image lines need to be within the loop and after  $news_query->the_post() since this is what populates your $post variable.

Comment: one more thing, as @Tom J Nowell mentioned in the comments above, you need to move the wp_reset_postdata() within the if. Since you are not calling the_post() unless you actually have posts, calling it in the esle does nothing for you.